# Problems with shiny-markdown and ggvis

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, ggvis

I have problems including a ggvis plot into shiny-markdown. For example, the Code

````
---
title: "testShiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, fig.height=3}

require(ggvis)
require(knitr)
require(shiny)

women %>%
  ggvis(x= ~height, y = ~weight) %>%
  layer_points()%>%
  bind_shiny("p")

ggvisOutput("p")


```
````

leads to `ggvisOutput` doing nothing while the Lines

```
women %>%
  ggvis(x= ~height, y = ~weight) %>%
  layer_points()%>%
  bind_shiny("p")
```

produce a Plot instead of declearing `output$p`. I assume `bind_shiny(vis, id)` is the problem here.

Any ideas how to fix this?

PS: my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmarkdown_0.2.55  markdown_0.7.3    shiny_0.10.1.9001 knitr_1.6.12           ggvis_0.3.0.99   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] assertthat_0.1  digest_0.6.4    dplyr_0.2       evaluate_0.5.5  formatR_0.10         htmltools_0.2.4
 [7] httpuv_1.3.0    magrittr_1.0.1  parallel_3.0.2  Rcpp_0.11.2     RJSONIO_1.3-0   stringr_0.6.2  
[13] tools_3.0.2     xtable_1.7-3    yaml_2.1.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no problem with the above code -- I don't think you need that `ggvisOutput("p")` or the `bind_shiny("p")`.  After I removed it, it compiled into a shiny-markdown document with the ggvis showing just fine.  Here's my session info:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.10.0   knitr_1.6      ggvis_0.3.0.99

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1   bitops_1.0-6     caTools_1.17     digest_0.6.4     dplyr_0.2       
[6] evaluate_0.5.5   formatR_0.10     htmltools_0.2.4  httpuv_1.3.0     magrittr_1.0.1  
[11] parallel_3.1.0   Rcpp_0.11.1      RJSONIO_1.2-0.2  rmarkdown_0.2.53 stringr_0.6.2   
[16] tools_3.1.0      xtable_1.7-3     yaml_2.1.11
```

EDIT: I compiled through r-studio: Version 0.98.977

You might have an old version of shiny/knitr/ggvis/rstudio .

EDIT2: I have included a reproducible example that compiles correctly in a shiny-markdown document:

````
---
title: "testShiny"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r defineWidget, fig.height=3}
require(ggvis)
require(knitr)
require(shiny)

widget = function(dataset) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = navbarPage("test widget",
      tabPanel("Dataset",
        fluidPage(
          ggvisOutput("gg_plot")
        ) #fluid page
      ),  #tab panel

      #END TABS
      responsive = FALSE
    ), #ui  

    #SERVER
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      dataset %>% ggvis(x = ~mpg, y = ~hp) %>% layer_points() %>%
        bind_shiny("gg_plot")
    } #server

  ) #shinyAPP

}
```

```{r callWidget}
widget(mtcars)
```
````

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know it compiles just fine if i leave out the `ggvisOutput` and `bind_shiny` functions, but for later applications it is relevant for me to call the plot inside a `tabPanel()` enviroment which is very restrictive when using with `print(ggvis(...))`. Did you install the packages shiny/knitr/ggvis/rstudio from github or using `install.packages`?

Comment: I installed the github versions.  I've have successfully called ggvis from within a tabPanel.  I'm not sure you want to `print(ggvis(...))` I believe you use `ggvisOutput(...)` in place of print.

Comment: I included a reproducible document with shiny/ggvis code that showed up correctly for me in a shiny-markdown document.   Can you see if the above code works?

Comment: yeah it works! semms like going the `shinyApp()` way makes `ggvis` work on my machine. Thank you